# Drop and recreate global index having list partition on the table

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE INDEX Index_name ON tab_name
(Co1) 
GLOBAL PARTITION BY HASH (Co1);
```

I need to drop this global index having list partition with new column added

```
CREATE INDEX Index_name ON tab_name
(Co1,co2) 
GLOBAL PARTITION BY HASH (Co1);
```

When I tried to drop and recreate the global indexes , I couldn't see the partitions

```
select partition_name from user_ind_partitions where index_name = 'Index_name'
```

Comment: Try index name as capital

Comment: Yes , I have tried as capital only ... still it shows only one partition

Comment: when i use like this 'CREATE INDEX Index_name ON tab_name
(Co1) 
GLOBAL PARTITION BY HASH (Co1) partitions 16 ' its creating all list partitions ... is that correct to use ?

Answer (score 0):

I have specified the no of partitions at the end and its now able to retrieve all list partitions from table for the specified index .

```
CREATE INDEX Index_name ON tab_name
(Co1,co2) 
GLOBAL PARTITION BY HASH (Co1,col2)
PARTITIONS 16;
```